# JQuery .click - exclude specific elements inside div

Tags: jquery

I want .click to do nothing IF the user clicks `<p>text</p>` inside the div, for everything else I want the div .click to work.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span>yes</span>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div").click(function() {

        alert("woohoo!");

    }); 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
   $("div").click(function(e) {
        if($(e.target).is('p')){
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        alert("woohoo!");
    });
```

check the target of the click. this way you dont need to bind another event.

Comment: Unnecessary `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: hard to say, without seeing the rest of the code. Its likely needed

Comment: use `return false` instead which is the same as calling e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() in this case. Check http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Don't use `return false`, it has different meanings in a jQuery handler, an html attribute handler and a regular `addEventListener` handler. Call `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` as required for clarity. You rarely need to call `stopPropagation()`

Comment: Hey! I know you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "div :not(p)" ).click(function( event ) {
        alert( "woohoo!" );
    }); 
});
</script>
```

This implies you don't care about text nodes as children of the `<div>` container.

Comment: Ok, I missed the "...inside the div..." statement. Here is the update, and the answer will be updated accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/n983hzvn/2/

Comment: Oh my god what a crap question, the description is not the same as the example demonstrated, again: http://jsfiddle.net/n983hzvn/3/

Comment: @FagnerBrack problem space `div :not` and `div:not` are different, warning a prevent!

Answer (score -2):

```
$("div > span").click(function() {

    alert("woohoo!");

});
```

But you'd better provide ids for your html element.

Comment: It doesn't work for span inside another children, the OP says for "everything else", the interpretation is that the code is not restricted to the children.